# Perl: Regular Expression for certain complex characters

Tags: regex, perl

I am a beginner at Perl and have a section of data like the following:

```
ATOM    2067  N    SER 7  316   -2.78500  -0.14800  -0.01300 N_R    3 0 -0.47000 0   0
ATOM    2068 HN    SER 7  316   -2.51586   0.06218   0.89490 H___A  1 0  0.31000 0   0
ATOM    2069  CA   SER 7  316   -3.57800  -1.36200  -0.28500 C_3    4 0  0.07000 0   0
```

I want to be able to print to another file lines of the data without H_ in each line. Could you help me identify the error in my regular expression.

```
while (<localBGF>)
{
      $line = $_;
      if ($line =~ /^ATOM\s+\d+\s+(\S+)\s+SER/)
      {

          if ($line !~ /^ATOM\s+\d+\s+(\S+)\s+SER\s+\d\s+\d\s+\d\s+\d\s+\d\s+H_/)
          {
               print BGF $line;
          }

      }
}
```

Comment: Why not just do `$line =~ s/H_//g;`?

Comment: Also, you are using `strict` and `warnings`, **right**?

Comment: @JackManey: I think he wants to check the begining of the line:`ATOM 1234...`

Comment: When a line contains `H__`, does the third field also contains an `H` (if and only if) ?

Comment: The error is that you're missing a `+` after some `\d` and also that `\d` matches digits `0-9` so `\d+` would not match `-0.01300` since it doesn't match `-` or `.`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already identified with the first regex that the line matches `^ATOM\s+\d+\s+(\S+)\s+SER` for the second you can just check that `$line !~ /.*H_.*/`